# Best way to queue message in SQL Server with several writers and one reader

Tags: sql, message-queue, service-broker

I wish to create a queue where a lot of computers would be writing in but each computer will write only once in his entire life. What you think would be the best way to achieve that?

I have read about SQL Server queues, SQL Server tables used as queue or service broker infrastructure.

- SQL Server table : pretty easy to create but I am afraid of the performance
- Service broker : more complex infrastructure. It seems that you have to run a service on the sender and have a send queue which is useless in my case because because all of them only send one message in their entire life.

What solution would be the best in my case?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to create a service on each computer. Service Broker objects can be confined to one DB server. For example, if you have 100 computers that need to drop of a message, they will need a connection string to the database server and execute a stored procedure that would enqueue the said message.
that said, it seems like a Service Broker queue would be an overkill for this. A simple table would probably suffice, or even better an MSMSQ (which would eliminate the need to connect to a DB).

Answer (score 0):

Our production code uses tables as queues. We don't really need the robustness of Service Broker, and all our code already connects to databases for other stuff anyway.

Our code doesn't need more than a few hundred transactions per second, and I've shown that our queue can achieve over 10k transactions per second, so I'm fairly happy with the performance.

Here's a great article describing how to design tables for use as queues: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

I would not design your table without first giving it a read.

Our company is also contemplating an alternative queue strategy involving Redis that doesn't require disk access since we are considering a design that would require tens or hundreds of thousands of inserts a second, but don't necessarily care about losing the data in the event of a failure. I would also give those methods a consideration if you need the throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the better way transform your whole system from "several writers and one reader" to "one writer and one reader"? I mean you may make some service (web or any other) who will receive requests to write and will be the only writer into your database. This is ordinary situation and has many standard solutions.